# Various ways to share R shiny app with coworkers

Tags: r, shiny, localhost, shinydashboard

I have developed a shiny app for my coworkers. They dont have any programming experience and dont know anything about R. So I would like to share the Shiny app through the local LAN.

What are my options to build a local server. How do I explain to my IT department the necceseties to get the app running for my coworkers to see?

Comment: Have you explored using a https://www.shinyapps.io/ account for free (public) or for a fee, depending on the nature of the data you are displaying?

Comment: Yes I have considered shinyalls.io. However the data comes from our own database and we cannot (are not allowed) upload it to a third party server. Its best for us to keep the data and the server in our hands.